# Monkey patching ENV in a Rails app end with ENV is not a class (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, monkeypatching

I'm trying to add some functionality to the ENV class of a Rails 4 App.

My initializer at `config/initializers/env_extend.rb` looks like this:

```
class ENV
  def self.enabled?(env_key)
    if ENV[env_key].nil?
      return false
    else
      return ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::TRUE_VALUES.include?(ENV[env_key])
    end
  end
end
```

Yet when I load the app with `rails console` it won't load, and the following is printed out

```
[mveksler:...web/lib/core_extensions/ENV]$ cd ~/Developer/referral-web
/Users/mveksler/Developer/referral-web/config/initializers/env_extend.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': ENV is not a class (TypeError)
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'%
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/mveksler/Developer/referral-web/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/mveksler/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: `ENV is not a class (TypeError)` you have tried to reopen `ENV` as a class, (with`class ENV`) but I reckon it's probably actually a module instead. try using `module ENV` and see what happens. Otherwise go look at the rails source code and find out what `ENV` really is defined as.

Comment: For all intents and purposes, `ENV` is a hash. You can check this with `ENV.keys == ENV.to_h.keys` and `ENV.values == ENV.to_h.values`. However `ENV.class` shows `Object`. Basically you shouldn't try and "monkeypatch" `ENV`. Just set key-val pairs

Answer (score 2):

ENV is not a class (or a module) it is a constant. This should work

```
  def ENV.enabled?(env_key)
    if ENV[env_key].nil?
      return false
    else
      return ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column::TRUE_VALUES.include?(ENV[env_key])
    end
  end
```

but I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Are you just trying to call `.enabled?` on `ENV`

Edit: I should add that Classes and Module are also constants but my point is that it is not a Class or Module.

Comment: @maxim-veksler if this solved your question, would you mind marking it as the answer. If not, let me know what you are missing.